# Current difference between pinMode(pin, INPUT_PULLUP) and digitalWrite(pin, HIGH)?

Tags: power, pull-up

Does pin 5 or pin 6 use more power if they're just being used as a signal to an external device?

```
pinMode(5, INPUT_PULLUP);

pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
```

.

EDIT:  Thanks to some links below, I hopped thru a series of threads until I found the website [www.gammon.com.au/power](http://www.gammon.com.au/power) which did tests with a 328 and found the following results with the pins disconnected (which is different than my question but seems relevant nonetheless):

In SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN:

- All pins as outputs, and LOW: 0.35 µA.
- All pins as outputs, and HIGH: 1.86 µA.
- All pins as inputs, and LOW (in other words, internal pull-ups disabled): 0.35 µA (same as before).
- All pins as inputs, and HIGH (in other words, internal pull-ups enabled): 1.25 µA.

Comment: See also [resistor - does INPUT_PULLUP use power?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16578/does-input-pullup-uses-power).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on the external device. If it has high-impedance inputs,
then it makes no difference. The Arduino itself has high-impedance on
its pins configured as `INPUT`. If the device draws current from this
signal, then chances are it will draw more current from an `OUTOUT`
`HIGH` than from an `INPUT_PULLUP`. How much more? We cannot say without
knowing the specifics of that device.

If you model the device as a simple resistor to ground (which is almost
certainly *overly* naive), then the current draw is

I = V<sub>CC</sub> / (R + R<sub>o</sub>)

where R is the value of the resistor and R<sub>o</sub> the output
resistance of the Arduino: about 25 Ω for an `OUTPUT` and
32 kΩ for an `INPUT_PULLUP`.

Comment: Thanks, for us noobs is the signal wire to most transistors/MOSFETs considered high-impedance?

Comment: @rfii: The input of a MOSFET (the gate) is high impedance (it's actually capacitive, thus high impedance for DC). The input of a BJT (the base) is low impedance, and it needs a current-limiting resistor.